# Calling an IMAGEJ plugin in another program

Tags: java, swing, jar, imagej

thanks for the help!

I am a senior student designing something for my school hospital so any help is greatly appreciated and might make a difference :).

The design involves using a video capture card to gather a stack of images. We then open IMAGEJ and import the stack of images. Then we create a 3D model of the imported stack in IMAGEJ using the plugin 3DViewer (a ".JAR")

In the interest of physician and patient time, it is important to streamline this process. Luckily, the capture card comes with a software development kit that we can tweak.

I want to add a button to the capture card program's GUI (seems simple enough) that will directly call to the IMAGEJ plugin "3DViewer" and send a selected image sequence, thereby eliminating the need to open IMAGEJ.

Is something like this possible? I have never worked with .JAR files. Also, as I change the development kits class files (which runs as its own .JAR file), how do I get the updated .JAR?
Thanks

Comment: That sounds like an easy task with some [scripting](http://imagej.net/Scripting) and maybe using available tools like [ActionBar](https://github.com/mutterer/ActionBar). No need to re-invent the wheel with some new Java code. Why don't you ask this on the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

As you use only ImageJ, you have to use the scripting language associated with ImageJ. Each ImageJ command/plugin/PluginFilter can be called from a script.